# unable to start "program.exe" the system cannot find the file specified vs2008

Tags: c++, windows

I am able to successfully build solution. but i keep getting this when i try to start debugging or executing it. any suggestions why this might be the case?

update:
i fixed the issue. I just recreated the proj with empty files and then just rebuild and it worked. one question: when i start the program (its a console app) how do i stop it from disappearing when i try to enter any input from within vs2008?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the debug command

*(Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command)*

is pointing to the output file built by your selected configuration.

*(Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Output Directory),*

*(Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Output File)*

Comment: looks like even though the build was a success the  binary was not created. can that happen that a program compiles and links yet fails to produce a bin exe?

Comment: What type of project are you building?
(Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Configuration Type)

Answer (score 0):

add a break point to the end of the program or wait for a keyboard hit

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to keep a console app from exiting is to add another input query so the program pauses until enter is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, maybe it'll help some one as frustrated as I was.  I was just hitting f5, which debugs the program.  I went to Debug -> Build Solution, or f7 and it built it and now I can press f5.  Super tiny little thing.  It normally works if I just press f5, but I'll hit f7 first now.

Answer (score 0):

To who ever still facing this in visual studio 2022 ,

ctrl+n or just adding a new cpp file wont do

go to SOLUTION EXPLORER >> SOURCE FILES >> RIGHT CLICK (DROP DOWN NEW FILE)>> ADD CPP FILE

Answer (score -1):

Go to the debug folder to see what `.exe` file build. after that
rename your `solution name` to your `.exe` file name to solve your problem.