# cannot find .exe file in Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So, I installed Visual C++ 2010 for the fifth time, I believe, and every time I debug a program, even the simplest c++ program fails to compile, and I get the following error:

`Unable to start program 'C:\Users\Ruth\sid\game\Debug\game.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified.`

I don't know why this is happening or if I need to create an exe file. myself. I need help fast. Thanks.

Comment: Could you put the error message here, instead of the image URL? It could help others who will search for the same symptoms. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program). Try to build your solution.

Comment: Please do not post images of text messages. It's lazy and wasteful. You can copy the contents of a standard MessageBox using Ctrl-C.

Comment: thanks, I'l try that to see if it will work.

Comment: 'Even the simplest program fails to compile' - then you should post the compiler error messages. The 'unable to start ...' message is a consequence of the failure to compile. So post your compiler error messages they are the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do the setup program of **Visual C++ 2010** includes a repair program? If it does, then run it and try to repair your *MSVC* by clicking the *"Repair"* button therein and following the next procedure, but it takes time to complete.