# Error: unable to start program "*.exe" the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I've downloaded visual studio 2015 and tried making a new visual C++ console project, but I keep getting an error which is this:
[Error image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY2qK.png)

I've tried searching many places on Google and tried their solutions for this problem but none of them helped me correct this problem.

Comment: Post a self contained question with a [MCVE] please. No images, just markup for code and error messages verbatim.

Comment: Try saving your project to other location, I encounter like this and becuase of windows permission

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the error's in the title.

Comment: Too many possibilities to be answerable with this little information. For all we know ninjas stole your hard drive.

Comment: @XBM, do you resolve this issue? Please share the latest information about this issue. I will follow up it in time:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The system cannot find the file specified" when running C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

Many possible reasons for the error messages:

(1) Please clean and build your solution firstly, and check the output window, make sure that the project compiled correctly. Debug it again.

(2) Please also check your output path.

I met the similar error messages and provided some possible reasons before:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc66d816-9a08-4471-8138-037ad2b0ffe6/unable-to-start-program-the-system-could-not-find-the-file-specified?forum=vsdebug

You could refer to it.