# Microsoft visual studio 2012 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am learning c++ from scratch and I was trying to make hello world program with this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but I always end with "this project is out of date"
and when I try to build it I have this error message:

unable to start program 'c:\users\User\documents\visualstudio2012\projects\Consoleapplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe'.
the system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program should fail if you do not include your default `#include <iostream>`, which implies that your code should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

These said, to fix your problem, look in the **`solution explorer`** box to the left. Make sure that there is actually a **`.cpp`** file there. You can do the same by looking the `.cpp` file where the **`.sln`** file for the project is stored. If there is not one, then you will get that error.

When adding a **`cpp`** file you want to use the **"add new item"** icon. (top left with a gold star on it, hover over it to see the name) For some reason **Ctrl+N** does not actually add a `.cpp` file to the project.

Sources : [System cannot find specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program)

Comment: Yeah the problem was that add new file isn't added in my project so it fails but by highlighting source files then adding new item it started perfectly, as for the # I added it but it isn't written in the question I don't know why

Comment: Okay. But I hope it has fully resolved your problem?

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are clearly not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: Okay @Ramhound. He probably was just stranded and he's only a new user who barely know the rules.

Comment: What does that have to do with answering off topic questions?