# Unable to Start Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, system

I have been trying to debug my program which I am unable to run it. It States " System cannot find path specified". I tried to do what was mentioned in in a post, but it did not work in visual studio. ["The system cannot find the file specified" when running C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program/36110671#36110671?newreg=fd702f821fbc4440aad23f8dcc5a237e)

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not only specifying the name of your files (for example in the  `#include` section) but also the path of them (`folder_name/file_name.extension`).

In addition, make sure that the file's path is relative to your programme's working directory. Software like Visual Studio tend to change the working directory from the path your .exe is to the path your whole project is located.