# C++ 'The system cannot execute the specified program' Error Message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have recently downloaded Visual Studio 2019 with the C/C++ extension. 
I have tried to implement a simple TripleX game. The program seems to be compiling and running fine until I ask for user input. 
As soon as I wrote

```
int PlayerGuess;
    std::cin >> PlayerGuess;
    std::cout << "You entered: " << PlayerGuess;
```

I am receiving the error message:

```
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

I have unblocked VS Code from my firewall, I have also tried installing the c++ build tools within the VS Installer, however I am still receiving this message?

Comment: Did you [search this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+system+cannot+execute+the+specified+program) to see if this question has been answered before? That's also not a complete [mcve], as the code you've posted cannot be compiled on its own.

Comment: Kindly check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program