# “The system cannot find the file specified” Error LNK1104

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-asio

I'm using Visual Studio 19 (16.0).

After adding the Boost libraries, I kept getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_73.lib'  Boost-Asio-Test C:\Users\user\source\repos\project1\project1\LINK   1
```

I added the Boost library to the linker and to C/C++ includes.
I basically attempted all of the recommendations found in this thread (["The system cannot find the file specified" when running C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program)) but I still keep getting this error.

Comment: Well, since those suggestions do fix it, maybe you can verify/show that you did the right steps and spelled the paths correctly. Show that you have the library in the expected location etc.

Comment: Your first step is to check if that file actually exists.

Comment: I agree with @sehe, there is very little we can do to help you if you don't show the steps you have attempted and show where you installed boost and show that this file does indeed exist and you typed this path into your linker folders ...

Comment: I double checked to make sure that I did everything in the guide was followed, but still I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm I checked and the file does not exist. I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: if it does not exist perhaps you missed a step when you compiled boost or perhaps you used a binary for x64 and want to build 32 bit code?

Comment: Side note: The Error List abbreviates the error messages to make them nice and pretty in a GUI. They look kinda crappy in text. On the other hand, the nearby Output Tab does no abbreviation, you get the full error message in plain text. This pastes into Stack Overflow really well AND sometimes contains a few extra tidbits that help you crack the mystery.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301 the output tab looks better indeed.

Comment: Now you probably want to add the exact detail on how you installed boost since the bug is in the steps you made to install boost.

Comment: @pkc you double checked. Fine. But you missed the essential point, because it doesn't work. So you need to SHOW what you checked, and how. Provide screenshots. Leave no detail uncovered (exact file names, times, access permissions, spelling of the include path in context etc etc). It is 100% guaranteed that the problem will jump out at some point. We can help, but not without the info