# Unable to start program 'MYPATH.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified. When i try to run a new 'hello world' console application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019

i am new and i was trying to learn c++, so i open my visual studio 2019, then create a new console application and click the run button.

This is the autogenerated code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
     std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

[image]

any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The system cannot find the file specified" when running C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511925/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-c-program)

Comment: If the compile competed successfully perhaps your antivirus deleted or quarantined the your executable.

Comment: Please post the error message verbatim. The title says *"MYPATH.exe"*, while the wizard-generated project is called *"ConsoleApplication002"* which, by default, produces a binary called *"ConsoleApplication002.exe"*.

Comment: No, that does not answer the question, i already check the other post before make this one.

Comment: the path is ok, i change that to MYPATH just to do not copy all my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, i go to Tools > Get Tool And Features...
[image]

Then i installed Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
[image]

and now my program works! Someone know the reason why the SDK is not installed by default?

Comment: You didn't mention that there were any compile errors. I guess we should have asked. Without the SDK installed there should have been around 400 errors building that would have shown up in the Errors List and the Output Tab.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.